Error When Adding Middleware to Protect Dashboard Route in Next.js Project
I am using Turborepo to create a Paytm like wallet, I have two next-apps, user-app, merchant-app and webhook handler in express.
user-app
├── app
│   ├── dashboard
│   │   ├── dashboard.tsx
│   ├── p2p
│   │   ├── transactions
│   │   │   ├── transfer.tsx
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   ├── api
│   ├── lib
├── favicon.ico
├── globals.css
├── layout.tsx
├── page.module.css
├── page.tsx
├── components
├── public
├── .env.example
├── .eslintrc.js
├── README.md
├── next-env.d.ts
├── next.config.js
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── provider.tsx
├── tailwind.config.js
├── tsconfig.json


I want to protect my dashboard route. I am using Next-auth for signin logic. What is the best way to protect my dashboard route.



Here is basic middleware for protecting your dashboard:
(middleware.ts - in the root directory of your project)
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;
  const token = await getToken({
    req: req,
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  });

  const publicPaths = path === "/login" || path === "/signup";

  if (publicPaths && token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.nextUrl));
  }
  if (!publicPaths && !token) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", req.nextUrl));
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/login", "/signup"],
};

suppose the user has logged in and has token he will be redirected to the dashboard.
Here is the detailed documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware
